# Date based LINQ query failing with change of month?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

So my app queries a db and retrieves a list of events falling within a range chosen by a start and end datepicker.  Has been working fine but now it's failing.  It looks like if the range includes dates from last month into this month (say last week) it's only retrieving events in May... My eyes are melting from staring at this but maybe someone can spot something I'm missing?

```
foreach (Employee ID in activeEmployees)
            {


                var worked = (from workDays in dc.Events

                              where (workDays.Time.Day >= PayPeriodStartPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Day &&
                              workDays.Time.Month >= PayPeriodStartPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Month &&
                              workDays.Time.Year >= PayPeriodStartPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Year)
                              && (workDays.Time.Day <= PayPeriodEndPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Day &&
                              workDays.Time.Month <= PayPeriodEndPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Month &&
                              workDays.Time.Year <= PayPeriodEndPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Year)
                              && workDays.Employee == ID.ID
                              orderby workDays.Time, workDays.ID                                 
                              select workDays).ToList();
```

Comment: what do you mean failing? Is there an exception thrown? Or does it just not return any matches

Comment: As I explained "It looks like if the range includes dates from last month into this month (say last week) it's only retrieving events in May..."

I find that it works for any range within one month but not that spans two months... for instance 4/21-4/28 works fine but 4/21-5/3 only seems to return May events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's face it, your code is a mess (said with good intentions).

If you are using something over and over again, create an alias for it:

```
var date = PayPeriodStartPicker.SelectedDate.Value;
```

Additionally comparing dates, by *days*, *month* and *year* individually is not the correct way to do this.

If I am understanding what you want, then it seems your entire expression could probably be broken down like this:

```
workDays.Time >= date &&
workDays.Time <= date &&
workDays.Employee == ID.ID
```

If you need to ignore the time I suggest using [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.truncatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Objects_EntityFunctions_TruncateTime_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__) and the `DateTime.Date` methods.

Comment: I appreciate it, very much, and I take it in the spirit (I think) you intend it ;)  The reason for checking the way I did was at (as I recall) a suggestion from a Telerik forum to eliminate the time.  I'll try to figure out how to do it your way, it's obviously much cleaner... but I still don't see why the new month has caused it to fail.

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestions and the kindness of not making me feel worse.  I rebuilt the queries using your suggestion and they seem to work perfectly.  (I'm self taught, didn't pick up coding until I was nearly 60 so some things that might seem obvious... ;) )

Thank you again!

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 its all good, we are all still learning, good luck

Answer (score 1):

The logic of this query simply does not work. Say you want everything between 30-04-2019 and 01-05-2019: all records with year 2019, months 4 or 5 **and** day greater than or equal to 30 and lower than or equal to 1 will match. I.e. it will never return anything.

I'm not sure exactly why you get the output you are seeing, but something is wrong either way.

I'd suggest storing the dates as a native `DateTime` so you can use its built-in compare ability.